# JQuery Ajax Post input Class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to send Ajax post to PHP.

This code works Ok:

```
$(document).on('keyup change',function(){
        $.post("suma.php",{name: "oscar"},
            function(data){
                $('#Resultado').html(data);
            }

            );

    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

But the problem is, How can I send the value of two input class like this and calculate the sum in PHP?

```
 <tr>
    <td><input value="0" class="sum1"/></td>
    <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
</tr>
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @JanDvorak but the problem that I dont understand is how can I send class "sum1" and "sum2" correctly.

Comment: find them, then collect them into an object, then send that? If you are stuck with the last part, check the documentation on `$.ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for you:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" id="text-id">Send text</a>
  <input id="source1" name="source1" >
  <input id="source2" name="source2" >
</div>
```

You need to include [success handler](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) in your ajax:

```
$("#text-id").on( 'click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'text.php',
            data: {
                source1: "some text",
                source2: "some text 2"
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log( data );
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: But the thing is that class sum1 and sum2 are input text of a table, and when I write something on the input text, i put "$(document).on('keyup change',function()" for on keyup send it in post.I only want to know how to send the values of sum1 and sum2 and in PHP calculate the sum of sum1 and sum2.

Comment: INSTEAD OF "SOME TEXT" PUT THIS `$(.sum1).val()`

Comment: I got Syntax Error on .sum of  

source1: $(.sum1).val(),

Comment: 404 Not Found I dont know why

Comment: not giving you the line where the error is occured?, anyways have you changed the url to your url?, and if you did all try to go to http://jsfiddle.net/ save your script and let me see it and then we can continue

Comment: everything seems to be working good, so where is the problem? i think that your php is what we should deal with.

Comment: Can you help me with the php code? I only want to sum : sum1 + sum2 and show it as alert or something

Comment: Ok Im done, was an Error on my code.. Thank You very much :)!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to give distinguished names/IDs to the two input fields, then in JS you can find the value of those two like $("#input_id").val(), then post them in ajax data attribute like posted by Jeffery.
Secondly, you will be able to fetch all the posted data in PHP via $_POST variable, then you can do whatever you want with the data return a response.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on how you tried and what was the request like and what did you get from PHP?

Comment: This is the correct PHP: <?php
if( $_REQUEST['source1'] && $_REQUEST['source2'] && $_REQUEST['source3'])
{
    $sum = $_REQUEST["source1"] + $_REQUEST["source2"]+ $_REQUEST["source3"] ; 
    echo "La suma es: ". $sum;
}
?>

Comment: seems like you get it right, but what did you get for $sum?

Answer (score 0):

You can send  it here;

```
$.post("suma.php", {
       src1 ; $('.sum1').val(),
       src2 : $('.sum2').val()
   }
```

---

And your php:

```
<?php
    if( $_REQUEST["src1"] && $_REQUEST["src2"] ){
    $sum = $_REQUEST["src1"] + $_REQUEST["src2"]; 
    echo $sum;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Oh it takes too much time typing on 4inch screen mobile.